# What is the issue in this unsafe Rust code so it works on Windows, but not on the Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, rust, memory-management, unsafe

*Hello, I know the code could be fully written without any unsafe code, but I am doing a research and learning how things work "under the hood".*

**Back to the topic**, I've written a piece of unsafe Rust code that in my opinion should work without any issues.

This is the definition:

```rust
pub struct Container {
    inner: Pin<Box<String>>,
    half_a: *const str,
    half_b: *const str,
}

impl Container {
    const SEPARATOR: char = '-';

    pub fn new(input: impl AsRef<str>) -> Option<Self> {
        let input = input.as_ref();
        if input.is_empty() {
            return None
        }

        // Making sure the value is never moved in the memory
        let inner = Box::pin(input.to_string());

        let separator_index = inner.find(Container::SEPARATOR)?;
        let inner_ref = &**inner;

        let half_a = &inner_ref[0..separator_index];
        let half_b = &inner_ref[separator_index+1..];

        // Check if the structure definition is met (populated values + only one separator)
        if half_a.is_empty() || half_b.is_empty() || half_b.contains(Container::SEPARATOR) {
            return None;
        }

        Some(Self {
            half_a: half_a as *const str,
            half_b: half_b as *const str,
            inner,
        })
    }
    
    pub fn get_half_a(&self) -> &str {
        unsafe {
            &*self.half_a
        }
    }

    pub fn get_half_b(&self) -> &str {
        unsafe {
            &*self.half_b
        }
    }
}
```

In summary it accepts any input that can be represented as an str reference, creates a pinned clone of the input on the heap, gets addresses that point to both halfs of this value and returns this as a structure.

Now when I do a tests:

```rust
let valid = Container::new("first-second").unwrap();
assert_eq!(valid.get_half_a(), "first");
assert_eq!(valid.get_half_b(), "second");
```

It should run without any panics and indeed that's what happens on Windows. It compiles and runs without any issues multiple times, but when it is run on Ubuntu I am getting an error showing that the addresses no longer point to a valid place in memory:

```
 thread 'tests::types::container' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `"�K\u{13}϶"`,
 right: `"first"`', research/src/tests/types.rs:77:5
```

What could be the issue here? Did I miss something?
*I am running this code as GitHub action with the following flag `runs-on: ubuntu-latest`.*

Here is an URL to the playground showcasing that this code runs without any issues:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d36b19de4d0fa05340191f5107029d75

I've expected no issues from running this code on a different OS.

Comment: I cannot find fault in this code nor can I reproduce on an Ubuntu OS. If this does have a memory error, hopefully `miri` would be able to find it, but it does not either.

Comment: Can you link to the GitHub actions run and yml file that triggers the failure?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I cannot provide a direct link, but here is the file: https://pastebin.com/5Jk1fPg0 and here is the setup log: https://pastebin.com/t2pb3Fx8 I've also tried to replicate it on Debian 11, but with the same results as on Windows. I think it's either an issue with my config or how the GitHub actions are handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Changing `Box<String>` to `Box<str>`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b655f785b06795259d5bf9e8542ceb87), which shouldn't affect the soundness, triggers MIRI.

```rs
error: Undefined Behavior: trying to retag from <2563> for SharedReadOnly permission at alloc890[0x0], but that tag does not exist in the borrow stack for this location
  --> src/main.rs:41:18
   |
41 |         unsafe { &*self.half_a }
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                  |
   |                  trying to retag from <2563> for SharedReadOnly permission at alloc890[0x0], but that tag does not exist in the borrow stack for this location
   |                  this error occurs as part of retag at alloc890[0x0..0x5]
   |
   = help: this indicates a potential bug in the program: it performed an invalid operation, but the Stacked Borrows rules it violated are still experimental
   = help: see https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/blob/master/wip/stacked-borrows.md for further information
help: <2563> was created by a SharedReadOnly retag at offsets [0x0..0x5]
  --> src/main.rs:34:21
   |
34 |             half_a: half_a as *const str,
   |                     ^^^^^^
help: <2563> was later invalidated at offsets [0x0..0xc] by a Unique retag (of a reference/box inside this compound value)
  --> src/main.rs:36:13
   |
36 |             inner,
   |             ^^^^^
   = note: BACKTRACE (of the first span):
   = note: inside `Container::get_half_a` at src/main.rs:41:18: 41:31
note: inside `main`
  --> src/main.rs:51:16
   |
51 |     assert_eq!(valid.get_half_a(), "first");
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This comes from `Box`, which cannot be aliased. While it's normally fine to derive pointers from `Box`, when you move the `Box` (by returning `Container`), Rust no longer knows that the `Box` has had pointers derived from it, and assumes accesses through the pointers are invalid due to aliasing.

That's why MIRI is triggered. However, I'm not certain what makes this undefined behavior. Your test results suggest it is, but can't tell you why. My guess is that Rust decides `inner` can be dropped as soon as `new` returns, since it's guaranteed to be unique. It may even optimize the allocation to never actually write any data (the pointer, length, and capacity of `String` in your version), since that data is never read, which would explain your runtime error.

You can fix this by storing pointers only, and implementing `Drop`. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5b0d24d1fba0665e2b8abc8517316d14)

```rs
pub struct Container {
    inner: *mut str,
    half_a: *const str,
    half_b: *const str,
}

impl Drop for Container {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // SAFETY: Nothing references this value since it is being dropped,
        // and `half_a` and `half_b` are never read after this.
        unsafe { drop(Box::from_raw(self.inner)) }
    }
}
```

I don't think `Pin` does anything for soundness here. `Pin` is used more in dealing with public interfaces. As long as you don't hand out any `&mut` references to `inner`, there's nothing to guard against. While you might want it for internal guarantees, your real guarantees are stronger than `Pin` since you can't use the value at all.

Comment: Okay I understand and see the issue here, thank you. However the interesting thing for me is why does this code work perfectly on Windows, but not on the Ubuntu. Do you have any ideas? I though that maybe the memory is managed in a different way, but I didn't find any clues online and also don't know that much about it.

Comment: @444RS It's likely also broken on Windows, just that the error doesn't manifest. But that doesn't really matter. It's broken in the abstract Rust machine, which is what you should be concerned about when writing unsafe code.

Comment: _"My guess is that Rust decides `inner` can be dropped as soon as `new` returns"_ -- That would be one heck of an optimization and would violate the as-if rule in many cases (think e.g. lock guards). Unless there is a _specific_ optimization for `Box<String>` and `Box<str>` then I highly doubt this is the case.

Comment: I can't find UB in this code, and the optimization you stated is clearly invalid. Assuming `String` does not have a uniqueness guarantee (which is the case today, even if it is not guaranteed), it's like holding a `Box<*mut str>`. The uniqueness guarantee of the `Box` clearly doesn't affect the pointer inside, and there may be other aliasing pointers to it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman so is this: 1) a rustc bug, 2) some other UB that we can't figure out, 3) an OS bug, 4) user error? Isn't String just as unique as Box (it contains a Unique)?

Comment: @drewtato It isn't (the compiler doesn't emit `noalias` for it. IIUC it emits it for `Box` and not `Unique`). It may be one of those you listed, but given that @kmdreko couldn't reproduce on Ubuntu, maybe this is the result of some misconfiguration.